# Slow self join on large table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 70 million rows which currently is structured like:

```
id    currentDatetime        expiration    delta    strike    bid     ask
1     2022-01-03 09:30:00    2022-01-03    0.05     100       0.85    0.95
2     2022-01-03 11:30:00    2022-01-03    0.05     100       0.65    0.75
3     2022-01-03 13:30:00    2022-01-03    0.09     100       1.00    1.20
```

For the same expiration and strike, I want to get the delta/bid/ask columns at time A and time B (eg. 09:30:00 and 13:45:00, for example).

I have this query which hopefully does what I'm looking for, but part of the issue is that it's slow to run across 70m rows. I've indexed the columns involved already. Any suggestions?

```sql
            SELECT a.id,
            a.currentDatetime,
            a.strike,
            a.expirationDate,
            a.callDelta,a.callBid,a.callAsk,
            b.currentDatetime as dateTimeB,
            b.callDelta as deltaB,
            b.callBid as bidB,
            b.callAsk as askB
            
            FROM ticker a
            INNER JOIN ticker b
            ON (DATE(a.currentDatetime) = DATE(b.currentDatetime)
            AND a.strike = b.strike
            AND a.expirationDate = b.expirationDate)
            
            WHERE (TIME(a.currentDatetime) = :fromTime
            AND TIME(b.currentDatetime) = :toTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a multicolumn index (currentDatetime, strke, expirationDate) in table.

*create index idx_ticket on ticker(currentDatetime, strke, expirationDate);*

Comment: I did add the index but it didn't seem to have much of an effect - query execution time still about a minute.

Comment: Try on more thing, instend of (DATE(a.currentDatetime) = DATE(b.currentDatetime) use a.currentDatetime = b.currentDatetime, because if you use DATE the index won't work.

Comment: The issue is that the data in the datetime field is formatted like "2022-01-05 11:30:00", so I would need to use DATE to grab the date component. Since there are 70m rows I'm not sure if creating additional fields with just the date and time would help or not

Comment: If possible, try to export only this table with necessary fields to localhost or another test server, is a good way to tune before you change the table structure.